# How can I use the shell from a docker image on files from the host machine?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

What command do I have to type to start docker and get a shell that has access to all my files or at least the home files on the host?

For example, I'm on a mac and I want to run ubuntu's grep on a file, or execute  a bash script using ubuntu bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an empty file named `hello` on my host machine at `~/Desktop/tmp/files/hello`

Use the `-v` flag to specify volume binding and read the documentation for [Using volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#choose-the--v-or-mount-flag).  For example:

```
docker run --name voltest --rm -it -v ~/Desktop/tmp:/my ubuntu bash
```

Says:

1. `docker run` Create a container named "voltest"
2. `--rm` delete the container when it exits
3. `-it` keep an interactive shell
4. `-v ~/Desktop/tmp:/my` Bind a volume on my machine at `~/Desktop/tmp` to the container filesystem at `/my`
5. `ubuntu` Create the container using the ubuntu image
6. `bash` Run the `bash` command in the container

Then whenever you run:

```
find /my
```

You get:

```
/my
/my/files
/my/files/hello
```